# Allocating/Deallocating Memory in Rust compiled to Webassembly

Tags: rust, memory, webassembly

**My Situation**
I have been trying to make an IO game with parts of the client in Rust, compiled with wasm-pack to Webassembly, which I access through Javascript. Rust is used here as a libary, and gets called when packages need to be handled and the game-logic needs to be handled. For it to be able to handle the logic though, it need the context of all the entities and the map in the game, which can be a lot of data. Now functions that need the game context are called hundreds of times per second and I dont want to implement any batching logic and just want to avoid the problem entirely. That's why I decided to use the memory system in WebAssembly (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/Memory) to store the gamestate so I can retrieve it easily from Rust.

TLDR: I want to avoid passing the game context (Im making an IO Game, using JS and Rust as WASM using wasm-bindgen and wasm-pack) from Javascript to Rust and instead want to store it in memory.

**Actual Problem**
How do I now Allocate and Deallocate, Read from and Write to this Memory? My current implementation (below)

- Allocation: Vec with Vec::with_capacity
- Deallocation: std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr to the context, len) and let the slice go out of scope
- Write: Set the derefenced value to T
- Read: Derefence a pointer with the type T

`lib.rs`

```rust
pub mod memory_operations {
    [...] Includes
    
    ///Write
    unsafe fn write_mem<T>(ptr: *mut u8, x: T) {
        let ptr = ptr as *mut T;
        unsafe {
            *ptr = x;
        }
    }
    
    /// READ
    unsafe fn read_mem<'a, T>(ptr: *mut u8) -> &'a mut T {
        let ptr = ptr as *mut T;
        unsafe {
            &mut *ptr
        }
    }

    /// Allocate
    unsafe fn allocate_memory<T>() -> MemorySpace {
        let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        let mut memory = Vec::with_capacity(size);
        let ptr: *mut u8 = memory.as_mut_ptr();
        std::mem::forget(memory);
        MemorySpace::new(ptr as *mut T)
    }

    /// Deallocate without getting T back and without calling the deconstructor
    unsafe fn deallocate_memory_raw(memory: MemorySpace) {
        let buffer = unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(memory.ptr(), memory.size())
        };
        drop(buffer);
    }

    /// Deallocate a Layout in memory as a type T and get that type T back
    unsafe fn deallocate_memory_type<'a, T>(memory: MemorySpace) -> &'a mut T {
        let ptr = memory.ptr() as *mut T;
        println!("Dealloc Type");
        unsafe { &mut *ptr }
    }
    
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
    /// Simple Wrapper for Layout and pointer to pass it to JS
    pub struct MemorySpace {
        offset: *mut u8, 
        size: usize,
        align: usize,
    }

    impl MemorySpace {
        pub fn new<T: Sized>(offset: *mut T) -> MemorySpace {
            let layout = 
            unsafe { alloc::Layout::for_value_raw(offset) };

            let offset = offset as *mut u8;
            MemorySpace {offset, size: layout.size(), align: layout.align()}
        }

        pub fn ptr(&self) -> *mut u8 {self.offset}
        pub fn size(&self) -> usize {self.size}
        pub fn align(&self) -> usize {self.align}

        pub fn layout(&self) -> Result<Layout, LayoutError> {
            Layout::from_size_align(self.size, self.align)
        }
    }
}
```

This currently fails when writing, seems to just not allocate or to allocate and deallocate the memory. Im currently just testing this as a binary instead of WASM file so I can debug the problems premturely.

**Question**
Im wondering if this is the correct approach of accessing memory this when compiling to wasm (If you think this memory thing is dumb, let me know). If that is the case, how would I fix this code to run as a binary and as a wasm file?

Comment: A reference to a slice (what `std::slice::from_raw_parts` returns) does not drop anything in it's `Drop` implementation so your `deallocate_memory_raw` does nothing except call `MemorySpace::drop` if it implements `Drop`. an empty body would do the same.

Comment: You should probably write tests that exercise your code and run them under miri the mid-level intermediate representation interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you are building a JS/Rust game using `wasm-bindgen` and `wasm-pack`. Why not simply use `wasm-bindgen` to do the memory sharing as well? As documented [here](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/contributing/design/exporting-rust-struct.html), it allows you to annotate `struct`s and methods such that they can be passed to JS and have an object-like interface where the methods invoke the Rust methods. The object itself remains allocated in the WASM memory.

If you want to do this yourself, for some reason, then at least have a look at what `wasm-bindgen` generates in the JS glue code. It creates a number of typed arrays, for example `Uint8Array`, that are backed by `wasm.memory.buffer`. Raw access to the WASM memory is then done by writing or reading this typed array. This is also what the glue methods do.

Using your code, I was able to create a `MemorySpace`, pass it to a JS function, the JS function wrote some data, then Rust could read it back. I used `#[wasm_bindgen]` on `MemorySpace` and its `impl` block.

[cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000437/allocating-deallocating-memory-in-rust-compiled-to-webassembly#comment137511390_78000437) points out a problem in your deallocation method: dropping the result of `std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut` will not do anything, since the slice is not owning. You want to restore the full `Vec` using [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts), then drop that.

I would also note that `MemorySpace` should deallocate in its `Drop` handler rather than with a separate deallocation method which you might forget to invoke. On a similar note, you should make sure that you retain a reference to a `MemorySpace` that you passed to JS as long as it is meant to be usable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will definetly look into this approach, but for now I've found a working solution shown in my response.

Comment: I would use this solution, but I have got 2 Problems with it:  
1. It forces me to make all functions that require the game-context to be a member of the GameContext class 
2. I have to make conversion functions for more complex types like enums (JS takes ownership of the persistent data because it's 'main'), which JS can't handle. 

I haven't looked too much into this topic, because my solution currently works, but if there are solutions/workarounds to these two problems, I will use this solution

Comment: @Illumin I don't know what `GameContext` is in your project, since you did not show it in the OP. Why do the functions require the context? Re 1.: you can export the functions separately, see the `fn named_struct_by_value` example [here](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/exported-rust-types.html). Re 2.: yes, unfortunately enums are not yet supported fully, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2407).

Comment: I kinda glanced over it in my situation, but GameContext is just the information about the game (e. g. game map, entities, etc. etc.), that say collisions functions need. It's the part I don't want to pass by value everytime I call such a function, instead accessing memory somehow.
But the first part I completely overlooked. Of course that works! I might be considering it now for the parts the JS can handle

Comment: I just figured out that JS does somewhat handle getting a reference to an enum. If you export the enum itself, it throws a compile time error, but if you wrap that enum in a struct, it compiles. You still can't access the enum in JS, but you can own a reference to it in JS which you can pass back to the WASM, which is enough functionality for me

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out with a bit of help from ChatGPT how I can fix my example. Instead of deallocating/allocating it with slices/vecs, I just use `alloc::{alloc, dealloc}`. The code works perfectly now, as a binary as well as in the browser. However I'm not sure if the use of `std::alloc` is a good practise and efficient.

`lib.rs`

```rust
pub mod memory_operations {
    [...] Includes

    unsafe fn write_mem<T>(memory: MemorySpace, x: T) {
        let ptr = memory.ptr() as *mut T;
        unsafe {
            *ptr = x;
        }
    }
    
    unsafe fn read_mem<'a, T>(memory: MemorySpace) -> &'a mut T {
        let ptr = memory.ptr() as *mut T;
        println!("Read");
        unsafe {
            &mut *ptr
        }
    }

    unsafe fn allocate_memory<T>() -> MemorySpace {
        let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(size, std::mem::align_of::<T>()).unwrap();
        let ptr = unsafe { alloc(layout) };
        MemorySpace::new(ptr, layout)
    }

    unsafe fn deallocate_memory(memory: MemorySpace) {
        unsafe {
            dealloc( // Might be depracated soon
                memory.ptr(),
                memory.layout().unwrap(),
            );
        }
    }

    
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
    /// Simple Wrapper for Layout and Pointer to pass it to JS
    pub struct MemorySpace {
        offset: *mut u8, 
        size: usize,
        align: usize,
    }

    impl MemorySpace {
        pub fn new<T: Sized>(offset: *mut T, layout: Layout) -> MemorySpace {
            let offset = offset as *mut u8;
            MemorySpace {offset, size: layout.size(), align: layout.align()}
        }

        pub fn ptr(&self) -> *mut u8 {self.offset}
        pub fn size(&self) -> usize {self.size}
        pub fn align(&self) -> usize {self.align}

        pub fn layout(&self) -> Result<Layout, LayoutError> {
            Layout::from_size_align(self.size, self.align)
        }
    }
}
```

This works for now, I only have to add a wrapper around MemorySpace for Rust to be able to infer the type of the of the memory, read it properly and run the deconstructor when shutting down. MemorySpace itself is only supposed to be used once as a ptr kept in JS, that is passed into every Wasm function and points to an index of all the memory I have allocated.